# Two sums in one query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb (Mongoose entity) which represent a financial entry in my app:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var transactionSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    description     : String,
    amount          : { type:Number, min:0.01, required:true }, 
    dateEntry       : { type:Date, default:Date.now }, 
    dateAdded       : { type:Date, default:Date.now }, 
    positive        : { type:Boolean, default:false }, 

    category        : { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
    user            : { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Transaction', transactionSchema);
```

I would like to give a balance of my transactions: my first approach was making a sum of positive entries, then another sum of negative entries, and finally subtract the negative one from the positive one:

```
async.parallel({
                totalPositive: function(callback) {
                    var matcher = baseSearch;
                    matcher.positive = true;
                    Transaction.aggregate(
                        { $match: matcher },
                        { $group: {_id:null,sum:{$sum: '$amount'}} },
                        function(err,result) {
                            callback(err,result);
                        }
                    );
                },
                totalNegative: function(callback) {
                    var matcher = baseSearch;
                    matcher.positive = false;
                    Transaction.aggregate(
                        { $match: matcher },
                        { $group: {_id:null,sum:{$sum: '$amount'}} },
                        function(err,result) {
                            callback(err,result);
                        }
                    );
                }
            }, function(err, results) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.json({error:err.message});
                }
                results.balance = results.totalPositive[0].sum - results.totalNegative[0].sum;
                res.json(results);
            });
```

I wonder if I can save one query by having just one returning both the positive and negative sum.

Any ideas? Or is this the best solution?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a conditional grouping and then just a final project to do the math:

```
Transaction.aggregate(
    [
        { "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "totalPositive": {
                "$cond": [ "$positive", "$amount", 0 ]
            },
            "totalNegative": {
                "$cond": [ "$positive", 0, "$amount" ]
            }
        }},
        { "$project": {
            "totalBalance": { "$subtract": [ "$totalPositive", "$totalNegative" ] }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,result) {

    }
)
```

So just evaluate whether to [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) the "amount" depending on what "positive" has for either `true/false`. Then in the following pipeline just use the [**`$subtract`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) operator.

Better yet, just set the "sign" of the value to "sum" in a single group stage:

```
Transaction.aggregate(
    [
        { "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "totalBalance": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                         "$positive",
                         "$amount",
                         { "$subtract": [ 0, "$amount" ] }
                    ]
                }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,result) {

    }
);
```

So there really is no need for the parallel queries when you can just do this in a single stroke.

The "meat" of each case is largely in the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator here, which acts as a ternary operator for evaluation. Link there, but if you are not familiar then this means a way of providing an "inline" `if/then/else` evaluation. So there is a "test" as the first argument, and where `true` the second argument is used in the return result, otherwise where `false` the third argument is returned.

There are other samples available in the documentation at [SQL to aggregation mapping](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) which gives several common examples for those who are used to SQL, or are at least used to the "declarative" syntax for problem solving.

General reading on the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) is recommended, as it is essentially in SQL terms the differnce betweeen `SELECT thisfield where anotherfield = "this"` to every other permuation of advanced SQL when compared to the basic [`.find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method invocation.

Comment: Sounds nice! I'm still a beginner of mongodb, thank you very much, I'll try then accept the answer!

Comment: @FabioB. Fair enough. Take your time. I was possibly a little too glib and did not provide sufficient links or additional explanation  at the time. But that is added now as well.

Comment: Where can I add an additional $match ? I want to include in the sum only transactions having {user:myUserId}.